# How to handle express session cookies on the client side?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, express-session

I'm trying to create an API with express that I will access using a React front end. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle authentication using express-session.

I used the middleware like follows:

```
var corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'dfgdfbgbdfgd',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false
    }
}));
```

Here is the Log in route (the local_auth middleware is just checking if the credentials are correct):

```
AccountRouter.post('/login', local_auth, (req, res) => {
    req.session.user_id = req.user._id;
    return res.status(200).send('Connected');
});
```

After loging in, I try to access the following route from React to check if the session is operational:

```
AccountRouter.get('/authcheck', (req, res) => {
    let sess = req.session.user_id;
    console.log(sess);
    if (sess) return res.status(200);
    else return res.status(404).send('pffff');
 });
```

req.session is undefined.
The front end code is just a simple axios request to the above url. I have no idea if I have to save the cookie to localStorage and send each for each request.

Here is the request to the authcheck route:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/authcheck', {withCredentials: true})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('waaah va te connecter');
    });
```

And the login request:

```
const data = {
        'email': e.target.email.value,
        'password': e.target.password.value
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/accounts/login', data)
    .then((response) => {
        const sessionID = response.data;
        console.log(sessionID);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> req.session is undefined.

If `req.session` is `undefined`, then you are apparently trying to use the session in a route that is defined BEFORE this middleware code:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'dfgdfbgbdfgd',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false
    }
}));
```

has had a chance to run.  When `req.session` is `undefined`, that means the session code has not yet run.  Even if you had a cookie issue that causes a prior session to get lost, you would still have a new empty `req.session` if the session middleware had already run.

So, since you don't show the overall order of all your routes, we can't offer a specific fix, but it appears that this:

```
AccountRouter.get('/authcheck, ...)
```

is running before your session middleware which is a problem for any route that depends upon the session.